# Apply a change to the last row of each group by ID in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the next dataframe, I want to modify two columns for the last row of each cluster.

| country | ID | counter | direction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENG | 0 | 1 | OUT |
| ENG | 0 | 0 | IN |
| ESP | 0 | 6 | OUT |
| ENG | 1 | 5 | IN |
| ENG | 1 | 5 | IN |
| FRA | 2 | 4 | OUT |
| ENG | 3 | 4 | OUT |

I want to obtain the following result:

| country | ID | counter | direction | exit_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENG | 0 | 1 | OUT | NaN |
| ENG | 0 | 0 | IN | NaN |
| ESP | 0 | 7 | OUT | E |
| ENG | 1 | 5 | IN | NaN |
| ENG | 1 | 5 | IN | NaN |
| FRA | 2 | 4 | OUT | W |
| ENG | 3 | 4 | OUT | E |

For the last row of each group, I increment the value of the counter column by 1 and create a new column exit_to, with value E if direction = OUT and country ESP. If the direction of the last row is OUT the column exit_to, takes the value of W if country = FRA and E if country = ENG and the counter in both cases stays the same.

For the behaviour of the exit_to column, I have implemented the following code.

```
def exit_to(country, direction):
    zone = np.NaN
    if direction == 'OUT' and country == 'ESP':
        #+1 counter
        zone = 'E'
    elif direction == 'OUT' and country == 'FRA':
        zone = 'W'
    elif direction == 'OUT':
        zone = 'E'
        
    return zone
```

I was using the following function:

```
last_rows = df.drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
last_rows['exit_to'] = last_rows.apply(lambda a: exit_to(a['country'],a['direction']), axis=1)
```

The problem is that I want the change to affect the whole dataframe and I don't want to get only a dataframe with the last rows of each group. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use `apply`, here we can use a vectorized solution with boolean indexing:

```
m = ~df.duplicated('ID', keep='last')
df.loc[m, 'counter'] += 1
df.loc[m, 'exit_to'] = np.where(df.loc[m, 'direction'] == 'OUT', 'E', 'W')
```

Result

```
print(df)

   ID  counter direction exit_to
0   0        1       OUT     NaN
1   0        0        IN     NaN
2   0        7       OUT       E
3   1        5        IN     NaN
4   1        6        IN       W
5   2        5       OUT       E
```

Comment: I simplified the problem believing that you could give me a solution using the function I made. Your solution is very good but I can't use it for the specific problem. I have edited the question, I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: @Carola Please don't edit your original question completely this will invalidate the existing answers.

Comment: @Carola Do you still have other conditions to take care of apart from what you have shown in the latest edit?

Comment: @Carola Here is the [code snippet](https://replit.com/@ShubhamSharma13/SeveralSpringgreenDemo#main.py) that you might want to try based on your new edits.

Comment: Thank you, the last edit contained the original full information on the problem. Sorry for editing the original question. I'll give you a check anyway. Thanks for the help.